# Need a suggestion for sharing revenue on a news paper website

Tags: google-adsense, clients, business-models

Here's the scenario. A local news paper company approached me in creating a news portal for him. But instead of paying me for the development we would just be sharing on the website's earning.

Now, we really don't have an idea on how much we can earn on the website because it would be our first time. So he just told me to create a proposal for him, so he could approve the idea.

1st Question:

My question is what do you think is the proper percentage in splitting up the revenue? (60% for me - 40% for the company is I have in mind...)

2nd Question:

Since we're planning to get the revenue from ads (Adsense and Clickbank), How can we make sure we do proper splitting? Are we gonna be creating a company's account for every Ad company? or we just need to trust each other?

3rd Question:

Is there any suggestions?

I hope my question is in the right section. I would also make this as a wiki, since i'm not looking for a definitive answer.

Thanks!

[added info] ----------------------------------------------------------

A small city in the philippines. Total Population is 150,000. 
We're not planning to get traffic locally since we will only be getting 20% of it (Most of them don't use computer). 
We are planning to get more traffic outside the country.

Adsense and Clickbank are just what we have in mind. Another is paid post. Other than that we don't know other option to maximize our revenue. Suggestions would be great.

Comment: Can you give us some idea on the scope of this? How many readers does the newspaper have? How many people live in the area covered by the newspaper? Which country?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the business model of the newspaper is partly based on ads, is there a specific reason you want to go with Adsense/Clickbank? A more obvious approach seems to take advantage of the current client base and cross-sell "normal" and online ads. I would assume you could achieve much more revenue per ad this way.

Comment: Adsense and Clickbank is just what I have in mind. I don't know other options. the current Client base are really small right now.  Can you please specify what are those online ads you're referring. I'm really new to Internet Marketing, and I have zero idea on how to monetize.

Comment: I know this is a really old question, but I was going to add some info in case others find this question as well. The ads JMB was referring to would be ads that you sell yourself. So you offer to place an ad on the site for a given amount of time and money, and the person/company placing the ad would pay you directly. So you would be taking care of it all, instead of using adsense. Many sites do this by having an "Advertise with us!" link to a page with more details.